# Cloud Functions and Express req.headers.cookie Undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, cookies, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions, and the [cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) module, and one function sets the "__session" cookie (the only cookie available in Cloud Functions) then executes a "GET" request to another function. In the second function when I try to get the cookie using `cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie).__session` it says it's undefined. I can see the cookie in the browser however, so I have no idea why I cannot get it in my app. I noticed there are several other SO questions similar to this problem that are also unanswered.

Here is the relevant code from the first function:

```
const nonce = require('nonce')();

const state = nonce();
res.cookie('__session', state);

request.get('https://myappurl.firebaseapp.com/myapp/path?state=' + state, { json: true })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.message);
    });

res.redirect('someurl.com');
```

From the second function:

```
const cookie = require('cookie');

app.get('/myapp/path', (req, res) => {

  console.log(req.headers.cookie); // This is undefined.
  const stateCookie = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie).__session
  console.log('stateCookie: ' + stateCookie); // This is undefined.

}
```

**UPDATE**

After adding my code, I realized that I'm setting the cookie on `res` (Express response) but making the get request with `request` (request-promise module). I'm thinking this may be my issue. I'm going to figure out how to set a cookie to the `request` and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, mostly. Turns out setting the cookie on the Express `res` was part of the problem. I should be setting it on the `request` object (request-promise). I tried a couple of ways to set the cookie on the request, including `request.cookie`. But the only way that worked was this:

```
var options = {
    headers: {
      Cookie: '__session=mytestheadercookie'
    }
};

request.get('https://myapp.com', options)
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.message);
});
```